# Reading a 4 band image with rasterio (python)

Tags: python, image, digital-image-processing, rasterio, multi-band

I am trying to view a tif satellite image which has 4 bands. I want to remove the last band (NIR) and view the RGB image only, so I am trying to split the NIR from the rest of the image. Here is my code

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from rasterio import plot
import numpy as np
#to display RGB
dataset = rasterio.open('2.tif')
%matplotlib inline
plot.show(dataset.read([1,2,3]), cmap="gray")
#to display just the red band
%matplotlib inline
plot.show(dataset.read(4), cmap="gray")
```

I provided a screen shot of the code and the output I am getting
[image]

Displaying just 1 band seems fine, but any idea why I keep seeing an image with a yellow and white color scheme when I try to display RGB bands together? I thought it's a cmap issue at the beginning, but even when I add 'cmap="gray"' the color of the image remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Reading and plotting works just fine, but the problem is in the warning you get from `matplotlib`:

- If an image has integer values `matplotlib` will clip them to interval `[0, 255]`
- If an image has float values `matplotlib` will clip them to interval `[0, 1.0]`

In your case all values were clipped to either `255` or to `1.0` and that is why you see a white image. Also note that this happens only when you try to plot a RGB image. When plotting an image with a single channel `matplotlib` won't do any clipping.

Solution - check dtype of your image values and decrease / change them accordingly. Example:

```
image = dataset.read([1,2,3])
print(image.dtype, np.max(image))
image = (255 * image / np.max(image)).astype(np.uint8)
plot.show(image)
```

This transforms image values to integer values from `[0, 255]`. (Instead by multiplying images by `255 / np.max(image)` you might want to try some other constant to get nicer image. I used this one because I don't know anything about values of your image.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure if I understand correctly. I tried your code above, and I replaced 255 with the maximum value of my image's data (uint16 --> 1286). But the image that I am getting is too distorted.
Edit: I also tried 65535 but I am getting a completely black/dark gray image

Comment: If you are working with integer values, you just have to make sure your values are properly scaled from 0 to 255. How you scale them is up to you. Scaling them up to 1286 or 65535 probably won't show correct image.